# How can I access my work Mac behind a firewall from my home Mac

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, vnc, screen-sharing

I'm really hoping someone can answer this for me so I can telecommute... I want to be able to access my work Mac from my home Mac, or just be able to somehow access the network. I do web development but the site is not accessible unless you are on the local network. For example, you can go to portlandonline.com, but not dev.portlandonline.com.

I figured if I can just access my Mac externally I can use it to refresh the browser and file. The only issue is that we're behind a firewall. I'm basically the only Mac here otherwise it's all Windows XP and starting to get some Windows 7 machines. I thought because it is a Windows firewall I could bypass it easier directly connecting to my Mac since the security people said that and that's why they don't like having Macs on the network... (I'm 99.9% that's rubbish, but whatever)

I turned on SSH in sharing > remote login and tried using my external IP, but it just sat there.

I turned on Remote management and also tried my external IP, but it just sat there when the other Mac at home tried using Finder > Go > Connect to Server > vnc://my.ip.addr.ess

Is there any way to access the computer outside this network? Are there ways to test if it's connecting at all and I might just be doing something wrong?

Comment: If you want to use SSH/VNC you'll probably have to get IT to open a port in the firewall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) or [LogMeIn](http://www.logmein.com/).

Your IT people at work will not appreciate this and it might violate policy.

Comment: The policy's there are a little ridiculous. For example you have to use IE8 and not Firefox or Chrome even tho we all know that IE is nowhere near as secure. Also, you can't even technically be on a Mac. If you want to VPN into your PC (except I want to go into my Mac) you have to use this USB thing that generates a new random number every 30 seconds and go through a browser (IE only) VPN client. I NEED to be able to telecommute. Thanks, it is against the policy, but my manager gave me an OK, so i can blame him if i get in trouble ;)